# MongoDB Attribute Pattern - assigning misspelled attribute names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I just read multiple articles about Attribute Pattern in MongoDB for designing a Product Catalog, and I still don't completely understand how it works.

What I didn't understand from any of the articles is where the attribute name and value are coming from?

Let's say we have a form on the frontend where a user wants to add a product. When he is assigning an attribute **"Size: S"** to the product, he just types from keyboard the attribute name (Size) and the attribute value (S)? Or there is another model in the back, having multiple attributes and their values, and he just selects the one corresponding to the product?

Because there can be hundreds or thousands of products that need to have the same attribute. And misspelling the attribute name, can create problems when searching products with a certain attribute.

Maybe my question is dumb, but I am pretty confused right now. If anyone can guide me on how this works exactly it would be great.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't really understand what you're asking but it seems to me that before you ask about design patterns you should go and play a little with client/server side code so you get a better understanding of the dynamics between the two. once you feel like you understand those concepts well adding database features to the backend is just a matter of technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows any attribute name to be used in principle.

If you would like attribute names to be part of a set, validate the names in your application prior to persisting them in the database. Naturally this requires you to know all possible attribute names.

If you don't know all possible attribute names or otherwise would like to allow users to add arbitrary attributes, indeed it is possible that users will mistype attributes causing issues down the road.

One way of solving this is what SO does when you ask questions here - popular tags are suggested making users more likely to pick one of them, but a mechanism is provided for users to also enter any tag they want.